# Self-Employed Individual 401k Contribution Tax Questions

Tags: united-states, taxes, 401k, self-employment

If as an unincorporated self-employed person, one contributed

- x dollars to my individual 401(k) personally
- y dollars to my individual 401(k) as my own employer

How are these two numbers reflected on a standard (2014) 1040 tax forms? Schedule C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You report *all* of your own contributions on line 28 of the Form 1040, you report the matching to your employees (if you have any) on line 19 (pensions and profit sharing plans) of your Schedule C.

Deducting your own contributions on Schedule C is not allowed because it affects the SE tax calculation (the 401(k) contributions are not exempt from FICA/SE taxes).

IRS has [a nice page with examples](http://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/Self-Employed-Individuals-Calculating-Your-Own-Retirement-Plan-Contribution-and-Deduction) on how to calculate the amounts.

Comment: If I understand this page correctly the "employee" amount above is in 1040 line 28.  The "employer" amount is entered in line 19 of Schedule C and reduces the amount in 1040 line 27.

Comment: @rhaskett you're right, I misread. Corrected my answer.